# Text wrapping in a rectangle in canvas using html5

Tags: html, html5-canvas, word-wrap

I am learning html5. I have drawn a rectangle using canvas and added text in it. Now if the text is longer than the width of the rectangle it gets cutted off.
So, is there a way I can fit the text within the recatangle by using text wrapping as I do not want to change the width of the rectangle?

Comment: I think you need a p paragraph inside, in order to get autowrap in effect ...

Comment: I have used context.fillText(text,x,y)  where context is the object of getcontext.  So how we will add p tag using canvas

Comment: I was a little to fast. You are using an explicitly graph 2D element, where the canvas - like SVG - does not wrap text. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is not any inbuilt function of canvas that can give such functionality like word-wrap CSS property.

But if you wish then you can implement it manually.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200">
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```